# Did Bathsheba receive the Get referring to her husband when Uriah went to war?

Tags: david, solomon

> And Jesse begat David the king; and David the king begat Solomon of her that had been the **wife** of Urias (Matt. 1:6 KJV) KJV  Matthew 1:6

What is meant by the family relationship described in the phrase "Σολομῶνα ἐκ τῆς τοῦ Οὐρίου" in Mattews 1:6?

[ἐκ τῆς τοῦ + S] has the connotation of inheritance, such a context can be seen in Gen. 31:1; 2 Mac. 8:10; 12:22; Wis. 19:18 and 2 Tim. 2:26. [ἐκ τῆς τοῦ + S] is different from the usual syntactic construction [ἐκ τῆς + S] for spawned child.

> Matthew 1.6 יִשָׁי הוֹלִיד אֶת דָּוִד דָּוִד הוֹלִיד אֶת אֶשֶׁת שַׂלְמָה מֵאֶשֶׁת אוּרִיָּה‏

> Yishai spawned David; David begat Sh'lomoh by his wife; the one who was Uriyah's wife. Matthew 1.6

This was also the interpretation of the Shem Tob's Hebrew Gospel of Matthew.

Comment: What do you mean by "Did Bathsheba receive the Get"?  What is "theGet"?

Comment: I  do  not understand this 'Get' either, Please explain.

Comment: Roberto, if English is not your first langage, please help us to understand what you are asking.  Are you looking for the meaning of the word "beget"?

Comment: "Get" in Hebrew is divorce document

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - can you please add this detail to the Question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the Bible proves this rabbinical tradition. Even if that was true, the certificate of divorce would be only binding after Uriah's death. David slept with Bathsheba when her husband was still alive. They were both adulterers. The fact that Matthew doesn't use her name, but calls her Uriah's wife, should be seen as that. She did not deserve to be named alongside Tamar, Rahab and Ruth.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ארקדיוס's answer that there is no biblical evidence of the rabbinical tradition that Bathsheba received a provisional *get* (divorce certificate) when Uriah went to war, and in any case this would not excuse her committing fornication/adultery while her husband still lived. But I would not denigrate her as @ארקדיוס has done by saying she does not deserve to be named alongside Tamar, Rahab and Ruth in the list of Jesus' foremothers. Bathsheba had virtually no choice but to obey David in this matter. The New Testament lists her along with the above-named honorable women for good reason, because, like them, she risked her life and her reputation in the process of perpetuating the messianic lineage.

A rabbinic opinion preserved in the Talmud (Sanh. 107a) relates that Bathsheba was providentially destined from the the time of the Creation:

> Bathsheba, daughter of Eliam, was designated as fit for David from the six days of Creation... but he partook of her unripe, before the
> appointed time. David would have ultimately married her in a permitted
> manner after the death of Uriah.

In this sense the parallel to Tamar is particular apt, for in both cases the patriarch takes a woman who is not properly his and yet God blesses their future marriage. We should also consider that she must have repented and suffered at least as much as David did after their first son died shortly after his birth. She went on to become the mother of Solomon and the ancestor of every other king of the House of David.

[image: Icon of Bathsheba and King Solomon https://loandbeholdbible.files.wordpress.com/2021/07/bathsheba_queen_cropped.jpg?w=1108&h=737&crop=1]

So, while cannot affirm that Bathsheba received a *get* we can indeed affirm that she is rightly named among the sainted foremothers of Jesus.

Comment: I neglected to say that in Matthew and Luke, Bathsheba is not exactly "listed"... She is referred to obliquely: "David was the father of Solomon by the wife of Uri′ah." But in the OT, Bathsheba was already the wife of David when Solomon was conceived.